# My ISP does not provide Static IPs. Which is the best and cheapest way to get Static IP online?

Tags: networking, server, static, vpn, static-ip-address

I access my `dev` server from home, office, restaurants and coffee shops sometimes.

What is the best and most economical service that I should use to get **one IP address**?

Have looked up on the internet a lot. Did not help much.

I want this problem to be solved here once and for all for everybody looking for something like this.
It shouldn't matter where I'm accessing my `dev` server from.

I need an online service to make my IP static irrespective of the network I am on.

Is there a service like this? How do I do it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After wasting a day I decided to use a `VPS` and `sshuttle` to setup my Static IP.

So, the cheapest option currently would be: https://www.arubacloud.com/free-trial.aspx

After setting up the VPS there, I used `sshuttle` to ssh into my `dev` server via my VPS.

This is how I did it:
`sudo sshuttle -r root@my_vps_ip 0.0.0.0/0`

sshuttle can be found here: https://github.com/sshuttle/sshuttle

Cheers!